# console.log prints "a" before class object [flow]

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, minify, console.log

Foo.js:

```
export class Foo {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

In a test file, I do a simple `console.log(new Foo("test"));` and it outputs: `a { name: 'test' }`

I'm guessing the `a` may indicate the `any` type (I do have flow installed), but I'm not sure.

Using:

- Node v10.15.0
- flow-bin ^0.90.0
- babel v6

Comment: Do you have a minifier running on your code? `a` looks like the name of the class, which is `Foo` in your snippet, but could easily be `a` after minification.

Comment: @loganfsmyth That's it, thank you so much!